# Add Array ID's to Label Text and List Box VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, label

Its been nearly a year since I messed with VB, but I am having an issue on my first assignment of the semester which is supposed to be a refresher. What I am supposed to do is make an application that I input a students name, address, GPA, age by textbox, and which year(freshman, sophomore, other) by radio, and classes by checkbox.

Once filled out I need to take that information and have it previewed in a label.text. If it looks right, I need the textbox.text info concatenated into a listbox. No matter what I try or do it either shows String.Array() in the preview or the program crashes at line 57 any help or insight would be appreciated.

```
Public Class Form1
'CIS259 Spring 2014 Matthew McQuarrie

'Declare Student Data as a String of 9 arrays
Dim StudentData(8) As String

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    'Close application
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    'Clear entire form
    txtName.Clear()
    txtAddress.Clear()
    txtGPA.Clear()
    txtAge.Clear()
    radFreshman.Checked = False
    radSophomore.Checked = False
    radOther.Checked = False
    chkCIS.Checked = False
    chkMath.Checked = False
    chkScience.Checked = False
    chkHistory.Checked = False
    lblPreview.Text = ""
End Sub
Public Sub btnPreview_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPreview.Click

    StudentData(0) = txtName.Text
    StudentData(1) = txtAddress.Text
    StudentData(2) = txtGPA.Text
    StudentData(3) = txtAge.Text

    'Find which radio button is checked to add to StudentData
    If radFreshman.Checked = True Then
        StudentData(4) = "Freshman"
    ElseIf radSophomore.Checked = True Then
        StudentData(4) = "Sophomore"
    ElseIf radOther.Checked = True Then
        StudentData(4) = "Other"
    End If

    'Find which check boxes are checked to add to StudentData
    If chkCIS.Checked = True Then
        StudentData(5) = "CIS"
        If chkMath.Checked = True Then
            StudentData(6) = "Math"
            If chkScience.Checked = True Then
                StudentData(7) = "Science"
                If chkHistory.Checked = True Then
                    StudentData(8) = "History"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'Show StudentData ino the text of lblPreview
    lblPreview.Text = StudentData(0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8)
End Sub

Private Sub btnStudent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStudent.Click

    'Add StudentData elements to Student list
    lstStudents.Items.Add(StudentData(0 & 1 & 2 & 3))

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Define "the program crashes" and define "line 57."  What is the exception?  What line throws the exception?  What are the values when this happens?  As an introduction into the development environment, this is a very good opportunity to work with a debugger.  In your IDE set a debugging breakpoint and step through the code to observe its runtime behavior.  This should give you a lot of clues as to what's going on.

Comment: `lblPreview.Text = StudentData(0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8)` this does not do what you think it does.  you have to concatenate each element individually  `StudenData(0) & StudentData(1) ...`  When it throws an exeption on that line (and others like it), it is a clue there is an error there.  `OPTION STRICT On` would help too

Comment: Thanks Plutonix you are a life saver. Now I am coming into an issue that regardless of which checkboxes are checked, the info of all go to the lblPreview.Text even if they aren't checked.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this approach I used here can help, but there a few differences..

my source is database.. I concatenate the fields in the database (the source)
and I display only the text, not the id on the listbox displaymember. you could concatenate the id to the textfield from the source and displya the fullstring contactenated.

```
'create the adapter
    Dim adapterU As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select id,nombre+' '+apellido as fullname from users", con)

    'create a datatable
    Dim datatableU As New DataTable

    'bring the info from the adapter (database) into the datatable.
    adapterU.Fill(datatableU)

    'relate the datasource (datable) to the listbox lsUsers 
    lsUsers.DataSource = datatableU
    lsUsers.ValueMember = "id"
    lsUsers.DisplayMember = "fullname"
```